# Filter out non-existent numbers on columns A or B in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. `df1` has the form

```
deva devb  c
   1    3  5
```

and `df2` has the form

```
dev
  1
  3
```

Now, I would like to join both dataframes so that I get only the numbers in `deva` **or** `devb` that appear in `dev`. In other words, I'd like to filter out the numbers that are not in `df2`. I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
df1 = df2.merge(df1, left_on=["dev", "dev"], right_on=["deva","devb"])
```

How do you join/merge with an "OR" of two different columns?

Comment: One way without merge is to create a new column in `df1` called `drop`. and then do df1.apply(), and check whether anyone of deva or deb is in dev of df2 or not. If yes, then set `drop` column to true, else false. Then filter by true and false on this new column.

Comment: could you show a more representative example?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1[['deva','devb']]=df1[['deva','devb']].where(df1[['deva','devb']].isin(df2['dev'].tolist()))
#   deva  devb  c
#0     1     3  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with `isin` + `any`

```
df1[df1[['deva','devb']].isin(df2.dev.tolist()).any(1)]
Out[76]: 
   deva  devb  c
0     1     3  5
```